# How to solve Error "Trying to get property of non-object" on Laravel

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I am trying to get the list from the Database, but the page showed the error "Trying to get property of non-object" please help me, I got stacked on this, here the code make error: `$status = ($employee->Profile->date_of_leaving == null) ? '<span class="label label-success">active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">in-active</span>';`

and below is the extended code of the file it self.

```
        foreach ($employees as $employee){
        $designation = $employee->Designation;
        $status = ($employee->Profile->date_of_leaving == null) ? '<span class="label label-success">active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">in-active</span>';
        $linkToEdit = "<a href='employee/$employee->id/edit' class='DTTT_button_small'> <i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>";
        $linkToDelete = "<a href='employee/$employee->id/delete/$token' class='DTTT_button_small alert_delete'> <i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>";
        $linkToView = "<a href='employee/$employee->id' class='DTTT_button_small'> <i class='fa fa-share'></i></a>";
        $Option = "$linkToView $linkToEdit $linkToDelete";
        $col_data[] = array(
                ($employee->Profile->employee_code != '') ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : 'Not assigned' ,
                $employee->first_name,
                $employee->last_name,
                $employee->username,
                $employee->email,
                $designation->designation,
                $status,
                $Option);    
        }
```

Comment: Show how you get $employees

Comment: Do you mean this? ($employee->Profile->employee_code != '') ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : 'Not assigned' , $employee->first_name, $employee->last_name,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call property of an variable that not object (maybe null, string or other types), this error has been occured. In this code you try to get `date_of_leaving` property of `$employee->Profile` and `$employee->Profile` is not object. So you can check object has that property by calling [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function:

```
$status = (property_exists($employee, 'Profile') && property_exists($employee->Profile, 'date_of_leaving') && $employee->Profile->date_of_leaving == null) ? '<span class="label label-success">active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">in-active</span>';
```

And this line:

```
(property_exists($employee, 'Profile') && property_exists($employee->Profile, 'employee_code') && $employee->Profile->employee_code != '') ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : 'Not assigned' ,
```

Comment: dang, i'm two minutes late :/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the your solutions but I got this error when tried it, "syntax error, unexpected '$employee' (T_VARIABLE)
"

Comment: Yes, you're right. I update my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but I got the another error: Trying to get property of non-object for the line to display the values: ($employee->Profile->employee_code != '') ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : 'Not assigned' ,
                    $employee->first_name,
                    $employee->last_name,

can you please suggest to write the right way for this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use same condition. `(property_exists($employee, 'Profile') && property_exists($employee->Profile, 'employee_code') && $employee->Profile->employee_code != '') ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : 'Not assigned' ,
`

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentionned tell us that you're trying to get a property of a variable which is not an object.

The line of code which produces the error is :
`($employee->Profile->date_of_leaving == null)`

Both `$employee` and `$employee->Profile` could return `null`
but in your code, just before this line, you wrote : `$designation = $employee->Designation;` which would have failed if `$employee` was not an object.

By elimination `$employee->Profile` is the reasons why you script fails. It may is not set or not an object :)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to having no data in database but you are trying to fetch it so you need to check it's null or not in each one.
I think this code help you.

```
$status = (($employee->Profile) && ($employee->Profile->date_of_leaving)) ? 
           '<span class="label label-danger">in-active</span>' : 
           '<span class="label label-success">active</span>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I got the none property object on different line. ($employee->Profile->employee_code != '') ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : 'Not assigned' , $employee->first_name, $employee->last_name still no luck :(, should I change this line too?

Comment: Yes change that line too

Comment: Try this one :-   (($employee->Profile) && ($employee->Profile->employee_code)) ? 
           (($employee->Profile) && ($employee->Profile->employee_code) ? $employee->Profile->employee_code : '' ) : 
           '<span class="label label-success">active</span>';

Comment: Nice, Thanks for both of you guys and @Mohammad Hamedani for the help. And thanks for the explanation by Robin.

Answer (score 0):

this error is actually caused by an 'internal server error' thrown by an asynchronous javascript. To see this error much clearly,  you can throw a response about the error to the web browser console, see below.

```
echo "<script>console.log(". $response .");</script>";
```

What the error is simply saying is that the asynchronous call made did not get any response from the PHP script it called.